# In Awk, how to call a function by using a string name?

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm seeking a way to call an `awk` function by name, i.e. by using a string that is user input.

My goal is to replace a lot of code like this...

```
if (text == "a") a(x)
if (text == "b") b(x)
if (text == "c") c(x)
```

... with any kind of way to dispatch to the function by using the string name something like this:

```
send(text, x)
```

In other languages, this kind of effect is sometimes described as reflection, or message sending, or dynamic dispatch, or getting a function pointer by name.

I'm looking for a way to do this using `gawk` and ideally also using POSIX portable `awk`.

Comment: A workaround could be, tointegrate the AWK script into a BASH script, and insert the name of the function to be called though a BASH variable, roughtly like this: `awk '{ print '"$fun_name"'() }'`. This is much less powerful of course.

Comment: A more powerful workaround would be, to use scripts instead of functions, and call them with `system(script_name)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using GNU awk 4.0 or later for [Indirect Function Calls](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Indirect-Calls):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function foo() { print "foo() called" }
function bar() { print "bar() called" }

BEGIN {
    var = "foo"
    @var()

    var = "bar"
    @var()
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
foo() called
bar() called
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this is perfect. Do you have advice for how to do it using pure POSIX, not gawk? (For this script, POSIX portability is a goal within a few months).

Comment: Yes, wait 5 years for POSIX to catch up with gawk :-). No, sorry, there's no good way to do it in POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
func alpha() {
  print "bravo"
}
BEGIN {
  charlie = "alpha"
  @charlie()
}
```

Output:

```
bravo
```

[GNU awk - Git Repositories](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/test/functab3.awk?id=1fbfd8)